# Routing same components with different parameters in Angular application

Tags: angular, routes

I have an Angular app with three modules that are using the same components with different parameters.
I used the demarche below, I do not think is a good solution, I used the preload strategy but I'm interested more in non duplicated components more than that. The state of every component is not important.

in **app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: './modules/module1/module1.module#Module1'
  },

  {
    path: 'module2',
    loadChildren: './modules/module2/module2.module#Module2'
  },

  {
    path: 'module3',
    loadChildren: './modules/module3/module3.module#Module3'
  },

  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/module1',
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

MODULE1

in **module1-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Module1Component1
    },
    {
        path: 'second',
        component: Module1Component2
    }
];
```

in **Module1Component1**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-module1-component1',
    template: ` <app-component1 [tabLink]="'AAA'" [columns] = "columns1"
     [displayedColumns] = "displayedColumnsA"> </app-component1> `

})
```

in **Module1Component2**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-module1-component2',
    template: ` <app-component2 [FormControl]="formControlA" 
    [tabLink]="'AAA'" [searchFields] = "searchFields1"> </app-component2> `

})
```

MODULE2

in **module2-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Module2Component1
    },
    {
        path: 'second',
        component: Module2Component2
    }
];
```

in **Module2Component1**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-module2-component1',
    template: ` <app-component1 [tabLink]="'BBB'" [columns] = "columns2"
     [displayedColumns] = "displayedColumnsB"> </app-component1> `

})
```

in **Module2Component2**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-module2-component2',
    template: ` <app-component2 [FormControl]="formControlB" 
    [tabLink]="'BBB'" [searchFields] = "searchFields2"> </app-component2> `

})
```

MODULE3:

in **module3-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Module3Component1
    },
    {
        path: 'second',
        component: Module3Component2
    }
];
```

in **Module3Component1**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-module3-component1',
    template: ` <app-component1 [tabLink]="'CCC'" [columns] = "columns3"
     [displayedColumns] = "displayedColumnsC"> </app-component1> `

})
```

in **Module3Component2**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-module3-component2',
    template: ` <app-component2 [FormControl]="formControlC" 
    [tabLink]="'CCC'" [searchFields] = "searchFields3"> </app-component2> `

})
```

What is the best way to maintain the same logic and minimizing the code and the load time ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that every module should be a component so that it we will not have duplicated code. This is not be good if we have heavy components.

Comment: You can solve ur problem with an observable(in a service) that share the info that u put as Input. Or if you use ngrx just dispatch and action and get the info you need from the state.